# How to remove iOS TableView Separator

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hello, thanks for reading.

I 've tried to remove these separators since a while, it's horrible I can't delete them. I have tried a lot of answers in stackoverflow but no one was helpfull :/

Here is the problem :

[image: UITableView Separator]

I can't remove these white spaces between cells :s.

I've tried :

- Change background color to same grey than cell,but it does not works
- Checking cell size

  Set separatorStyle to UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None

  Returning the good height with tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat

  Disabling separator in main storyboard

... I really don't understand how to remove these white space ...

Sorry for my english,

Thanks

I'm adding this. Now you can check my settings : (And you can see separators are disabled)

[image: Settings uitableview]

Comment: It looks like it's not a separator but simply space between cells. Do you have any headers/footers? Try setting header background colour to cell background colour and see if the white space is still there.

Comment: for me the  UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None solution is working perfect having de code in the - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style function. I don't know if there is a way for you to send me de project!! it would be much easier to help you in this way :)

Comment: check,reduce the height of cell and add tableview background color. then attached the screen here. are you using custom cell?

Comment: My tableView have a grey background-color. I'm using custom cell, yes, but I have set the good height :s

Comment: Seems like every other cell is a different size. It almost seems intentional. Is this your code that generates this? Could you post your cellForIndexPath function? And perhaps any setup function you have in your cell if there is any custom cells in the table?

Comment: Thanks Animal, the problem was on my cellForIndexPath function... I find this thanks to your answer ! I'm sorry for this ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'm sorry, the problem was on my code, so you could not answer me ...

It was in my function : tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

Somewhere I wanted a border on my cell, so I have write:

```
var layer: CALayer = cell.layer
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.rgbaColor(red: 288, green: 83, blue: 88, alpha: 1).CGColor
        layer.borderWidth = 2
```

But this code didn't work because red:288 should be red:188, so I had a white border instead of an error, and I did not noticed ... Sorry for this, thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

you just need to change this in the Attribute inspector:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this tableView method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat 
{
    return 0.00001
}
```

Comment: It does not work :s. I just need all the background to be same grey than cell :s

Comment: try to set self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor();

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it will be help full to you.

**Objective C :**

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.1f;
}
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] ;
}
```

**Swift :**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.1f
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not work... I've already tried this by setting footer and header section to the minimum in my mainstoryboard :/

Answer (score 0):

set the **tableviewcell** separator **none** likewise the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2yje.jpg

Comment: this is only the way. to check again you need to create table observe the seperator

Answer (score 0):

In swift hiding the table view separator

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell!, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) 
{
   cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

Comment: I have do this since the beginning... it's like if it is not separators :/

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: If it works,please tick and up vote my answer.Because it is helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell!, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    // Remove seperator inset
    if cell.respondsToSelector("setSeparatorInset:") {
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }

    // Prevent the cell from inheriting the Table View's margin settings
    if cell.respondsToSelector("setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:") {
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    }

   // Explictly set your cell's layout margins
   if cell.respondsToSelector("setLayoutMargins:") {
       cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the footer view to empty view:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

so separator will disappear for empty cells (you still keep separator for normal cells).

Answer (score 0):

In objective c

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor myColor]];
```

In Swift

```
tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clear
```